# Three.js scene to obj file

Tags: three.js, export, scene

I tray to export all scene in three.js with OBJExporter like that:

```
var exporter = new THREE.OBJExporter();
exporter.parse(scene);
```

And next to file:

```
var blob = new Blob([exporter], {'type': 'text/plain'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = url;
if (!name) a.download = document.getElementById('txtProjName').value + " ID " + guiProject.id;
else a.download = name;
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

It create a file but in it is only:

```
[object Object]
```

I don't know how to set type ('type': 'text/plain').
Is it a simple way to export all scene to obj file (or similar file that can be import to three.js like json file)?

Comment: should you be saving the returned value of `exporter.parse` to a variable?  `var objscene = exporter.parse(scene);` Then using that value in the Blob constructor? `var blob = new Blob([objscene], {'type': 'text/plain'});`. Just a thought, haven't tried it.